# How to assign managed identity from resources in different subscriptons

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

Below is the scenario:

We have three VM's in three different subscriptions they require to connect with common service such as storage account with MI. In this case do i need to create three different MIs because the source is in three different subscriptions or can i use user assigned MI and use the same MI with three VM's to connect with storage (1:1 relationship) even if they are in different subs in Azure?

Or would we have to use three different MIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can i use user assigned MI and use the same MI with three VM's to connect with storage (1:1 relationship) even if they are in different subs in Azure?

Yes, you can.

Essentially the user-assigned identity is a service principal in your Azure AD tenant, you can add it to the VMs in different subscriptions, the requirement is the subscriptions need to locate in the same AAD tenant.

After adding the user-assigned identity to a resource in a different subscription, it appears as below.

[image]

If you want to access the storage with the user-assigned identity of a VM, you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-vm-windows-access-storage), this doc applies to the system-assigned identity, for user-assigned identity, you need to specify the `client_id` of the user-assigned identity when you get the token, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-ua-arm).

Comment: Is't the MI scope is subscription? As per your comments, same user assigned MI can be used as a source in different subscriptions. How about system assigned, can that be done as well? In case, i enable system managed identity on a VM and then move the VM to a different subscription can i still use it?

Comment: @James The system-assigned identity of the one VM just can be used for the specific VM, if you move the VM to a different subscription, you can still use it, but also just can use it in the only one VM. So in your case, if you want to use the identity for several VMs, your option is user-assigned identity , not system-assigned identity .